# Android : Recreate Map Toolbar : Open In Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

So I am building a map that shows locations (markers).  I don't want to use the Map ToolBar (which has directions and open in Google Maps button) however I do want to make my own button that opens in GoogleMaps with directions to that marker.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Or if not working try this according to this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393"));
    startActivity(intent);
```